# How to return a FileStreamResult from Azure Storage

Tags: c#, azure-blob-storage

(This will be self-answered as there are no existing answers to this question, at least none that I could find).

I would like to return a FileStreamResult, getting the file from Azure Storage.  How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

This took me quite a while to get a working sample going, so here it is:

```
var blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient("<Your_Connection_String>");

var containerClient = blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient("<Your_Folder_Name");

var blockBlob = containerClient.GetBlockBlobClient("Your_Azure_File_name");

//Da magic here
Stream stream = blockBlob.OpenRead(); 
var result = new FileStreamResult(stream, "Your_Content_type")
{
      FileDownloadName = "Your_User_Friendly_File_name"
};
return result;
```